# Компилятор выдает ошибку из-за ItemView

Tags: android, kotlin

Только начал изучать Котлин. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему "ругается" Котлин на itemView. Вот сам код.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class RecyclerAdapter (var movieList: ArrayList<Movie>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
       class ViewHolder (item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(**itemView**) { 
  }
}
```

---

```
Продолжение темы:

class RecyclerAdapter (var movieList: ArrayList<Movie>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    fun bind(movie: Movie) {
        itemView.   <---теперь здесь ругается :(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewHolder (item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) { 
                  ^^^^                                  ^^^^
```

Comment: Оперативно .Спасибо большое

Comment: @АльфредАхметгалеев Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.